# Query on UIWebView

Tags: iphone

Can anyone point me some good examples on how to use UIWebView in iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code for using UIWebview

Hope this gives you an idea for using it

```
CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0); 
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame]; 
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com"; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]; 
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[webView loadRequest:requestObj]; 
[self addSubview:webView]; 
[webView release];
```

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is really easy to understand.

Comment: Always welcome... Bt getting a vote is the best thank :-)

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a couple of sample code projects:

> [UICatalog](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/uicatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)
>
> Web - Shows how to properly use a
>   UIWebView and target websites using
>   NSURL class.

and

> [TransWeb](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TransWeb/Introduction/Intro.html)
>
> Demonstrates how to implement UIWebView with a transparent background.